# How to post a jsf data in Android

Tags: android, post, jsf-2, http-post

Can I post a jsf form data in Android?For example this jsf page ;

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0">
            <h:outputLabel value="Adınız : "/>
            <h:inputText value="#{pd.ad}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value=""/>
            <h:commandButton value="Gönder" action="#{pd.kontrol()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
<h:outputText value="#{pd.sonuc}" />
```

I want to post "ad" data in Android.Here is my Android codes;

```
private TextView postData;
private String url = "http://localhost:8084/AndroidIc_nPOSTsayfa";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    postData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postData);

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("#{pd.sonuc}", "Mesut Emre"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,responseHandler);
        System.out.println(response);
        postData.setText("Alınan veri:"+response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I runt the app there is no error but I cant see my sended data on textview.

Comment: Is that response is printed or not.. in log

Comment: Please, describe deeper what you want to achieve. What are you exactly trying to do? Do you have any error?

Comment: No ,I have no error. But I can't see any result on textview.

Comment: I have a local jsf page. I want to achive that showing on textbox that come from jsf form.In the other words making post in android.